# TypeError: Cannot read property 'JsonRpcProvider' of undefined

Tags: solidity, javascript, testing

I get this error when I run `npm hardhat test` on my sample-test.js file and I have no idea why it happens, here is the test code file:

```
// Import the necessary dependencies
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

// Describe the EcoNexus contract
describe("EcoNexus", function () {
  // Define the variables to be used in the tests
  let econexus;
  let owner;
  let renter;
  let asset;

  // Deploy the EcoNexus contract before each test
  beforeEach(async function () {
    [owner, renter] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const EcoNexus = await ethers.getContractFactory("EcoNexus");
    econexus = await EcoNexus.deploy();
    await econexus.deployed();
  });

  // Test the createAsset function
  describe("createAsset", function () {
    it("should create a new asset", async function () {
      await econexus.createAsset("Test Asset", "Test Category");
      asset = await econexus.getAsset(1);
      expect(asset.name).to.equal("Test Asset");
      expect(asset.category).to.equal("Test Category");
      expect(asset.owner).to.equal(owner.address);
      expect(asset.available).to.equal(true);
    });
  });

  // Test the setAvailability function
  describe("setAvailability", function () {
    it("should change the availability of an asset", async function () {
      await econexus.createAsset("Test Asset", "Test Category");
      await econexus.setAvailability(1, false);
      asset = await econexus.getAsset(1);
      expect(asset.available).to.equal(false);
    });
  });

  // Test the rentAsset function
  describe("rentAsset", function () {
    it("should rent an available asset", async function () {
      await econexus.createAsset("Test Asset", "Test Category");
      await econexus.rentAsset(1);
      asset = await econexus.getAsset(1);
      expect(asset.available).to.equal(false);
      expect(await econexus.ownerOf(1)).to.equal(renter.address);
    });

    it("should not rent an unavailable asset", async function () {
      await econexus.createAsset("Test Asset", "Test Category");
      await econexus.rentAsset(1);
      await expect(econexus.rentAsset(1)).to.be.revertedWith(
        "Asset is not available for rent."
      );
    });
  });

  // Test the returnAsset function
  describe("returnAsset", function () {
    it("should return a rented asset", async function () {
      await econexus.createAsset("Test Asset", "Test Category");
      await econexus.rentAsset(1);
      await econexus.returnAsset(1);
      asset = await econexus.getAsset(1);
      expect(asset.available).to.equal(true);
      expect(await econexus.ownerOf(1)).to.equal(owner.address);
    });

    it("should not return an asset if not rented by the caller", async function () {
      await econexus.createAsset("Test Asset", "Test Category");
      await econexus.rentAsset(1);
      await expect(econexus.connect(owner).returnAsset(1)).to.be.revertedWith(
        "Only the renter can retrun the asset."
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the smart contract that I want to test:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract EcoNexus is ERC721 {
    uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;
    struct Asset {
        uint256 id;
        string name;
        string category;
        address owner;
        bool available;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Asset) private _assets;

    constructor() ERC721("EcoNexusAsset", "ENA") {
        _tokenIdCounter = 1;
    }

    function createAsset(string memory name, string memory category) public {
        uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter;
        _mint(msg.sender, tokenId);
        _assets[tokenId] = Asset(tokenId, name, category, msg.sender, true);
        _tokenIdCounter += 1;
    }

    function getAsset(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (Asset memory) {
        return _assets[tokenId];
    }

    function setAvailability(uint256 tokenId, bool available) public {
        require(msg.sender == _assets[tokenId].owner, "Only the owner can change availability.");
        _assets[tokenId].available = available;
    }

    function rentAsset(uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(_assets[tokenId].available, "Asset is not available for rent.");
        _assets[tokenId].available = false;
        safeTransferFrom(_assets[tokenId].owner, msg.sender, tokenId);
    }

    function returnAsset(uint256 tokenId) public {
        require(msg.sender == ownerOf(tokenId), "Only the renter can retrun the asset.");
        _assets[tokenId].available = true;
        safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, _assets[tokenId].owner, tokenId);
    }
}
```

Comment: gm, can you post too, your hardhat.config.ts?

Comment: Yes, please provide your config. Lets see what versions of hardhat, ethers, etc. do you use. Wild guess, but its either about your configuration or your ethers version you use.

Comment: `require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
const fs = require("fs");
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    hardhat: {
      chainID: 137,
    },
    mumbai: {
      url: `https://polygon-mumbai.infura.io/v3/94f07055be61499690c1ffe0c4826707`,
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: `https://polygon-mainnet.infura.io/v3/94f07055be61499690c1ffe0c4826707`,
      accounts: [privateKey],
    },
  },
  solidity: "0.8.18",
};
`